# Question about weight and newton metres

Tags: mechanical-engineering

A Caterpillar's weight is 150 tons (i.e 1,471,050 newtons).
Can this same Caterpillar's engine, hydraulic drive mechanism and  hydraulic motors, if modified, be used on a rotary (stationary) equipment (similar to a conveyor system) which requires a torque of 950,000 Nm?

Assuming the rotary equipment has a pulley of one meter radius and the four hydraulic wheel motors of the Caterpillar are arranged and positioned at equal distance around the pulley to drive it via chain or gear mesh.

My question again is: Can this drive mechanism of the Caterpillar which can move 1,471,050 newtons with ease operate the  rotational equipment requiring  a torque of 950,000 Nm?
The speed of rotation of the equipment is not relevant at this point.

Comment: Not in the config you describe unless the Caterpillar is able to lift itself up almost directly against gravity.  But all in all, yes; even a 3V toy motor can create 950,000 Nm of torque with the right gearing...as long as you don't need speed.  I suggest you look at power instead- how fast do you need to turn something at 950,000Nm?

Comment: I have seen 3rd party manufactures create mining rock processing equipment with Caterpillar undercarriage parts.  These manufacturers with Caterpillar's OEM solutions division.